# PHP variables to javascript, does not work

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a problem with PHP and Javascript variable communication. I have this code:

```
<?php
$php_var = 'lol';
?>

<html>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var php_var = "<?php echo $php_var; ?>";

alert(php_var);

</script>
</html>
```

This code does not work (as intended) for some reason. I cannot get the PHP variable's value passed down to Javascript variable. For some reason, Javascript completely ignores the php tags and assigns php_var a value of "". So it alerts the literal php code I put it as.

What am I doing wrong? I have been stuck on this problem for 3 hours. Is it my server's problem? (Using web hosting, dedicated). Thank you

Comment: Just so we're certain, you named the file with a `.php` extension correct?

Comment: What can I do to solve this problem? Use AJAX?

Comment: I copy+pasted the code in your example as-is and it works perfectly fine. I received an alert with `lol` in it in both FireFox and IE.

Comment: @KalonCheong thats your problem, the file need to have extension of .php

Comment: YES, it works with .php. Can someone explain why?

Comment: @KalonCheong — Servers are usually configured to run .php files through the PHP engine but not .html files.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) to ensure you get a valid JavaScript expression (otherwise characters such as newlines and quotes will break things):

```
var php_var = <?php echo json_encode($php_var); ?>;
```

You also need to ensure PHP is actually enabled for the file. This is usually achieved by giving the file a `.php` extension.

Comment: He needs a JavaScript string. `json_encode` will give him a valid JavaScript string when fed a string.

Comment: Ironically, it won't give valid JSON when fed a string :)

Comment: But a valid *JavaScript string/expression*

Comment: Oh yes, valid JavaScript, just not JSON.

Comment: thought about that, worked for me just perfect

Answer (score 1):

Use .php file extension and this will work.

If not then you variable won't have a value, you can see the exact issue by using something like firebug.

Comment: No, it will not, PHP won't be executed inside strings.

Comment: @nico — There aren't any strings with PHP in them … unless you mean the JavaScript string (in which case you are wrong, PHP doesn't refuse to enter code mode just because the template has a quote character in it).

Comment: @Quentin: my bad, you are right

Answer (score 1):

You say that the file where your code is located has an .html extension, it should be .php for it to render the php code.

Comment: Of course that is not necessarily true. It depends on the webserver configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can rename the file to .php and it should work or you can do the following thing:
Create a .htaccess file,
Add the following code ->

```
RewriteEngine On
<FilesMatch "(file.html)">
    SetHandler php5-script
</FilesMatch>
```

save the file,
then in the html file add the following php line at the beggining ->
 
than you can write php code inside the selected html file

Or you can add the following rule

```
 RewriteEngine On
 file.html file.php
```